# How to draw over a fresh copy of Timage with Canvas.CopyRect()

Tags: delphi

I have a code to draw a moving line over timage, and I want the previous old line always to disappear, but this code makes all lines to appears there for ever...  When I enable DoubleBuffering to form, the code below works OK  but the background bitmap located in myimg  does not show at all.

```
  Fbitmap.Canvas.Pen.Color:=clRed;
  Fbitmap.Canvas.Pen.Width:=2;
  Fbitmap.Canvas.MoveTo(Xo,Yo);
  Fbitmap.Canvas.LineTo(Xs,Ys);
  myimg.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect(0, 0, Width, Height), FBitmap.Canvas, Rect(0, 0, Width, Height));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not surprising that this happens. `TImage` is intended for static images. When you draw on its canvas, what you draw stays there. That is by design.

It seems to me that you have chosen the wrong control. Obvious candidates for this are:

- A `TPaintBox`. In the `OnPaint` handler draw the background, and then the lines.
- A custom control that draws the background in response to `WM_ERASEBKGND`, and the foreground in response to `WM_PAINT`.

The latter option may be overkill for you but in my experience is the best defence against flickering.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can accomplish this. The easiest one is to leave the image as is, and to add another component (TShape) which you will move *over* the image.

If you have to write the line on the image, you need to keet the original image in the memory and use CopyRect over the one with the line before drawing a new one. Faster variation of this method is to keep in memory only the part of the image where the line will be drawn, so you can copy it over the line later, thus deleting it.

Comment: Hello I like the idea of placing another component TPaintBox over TImage.  Then I just update TPaintBox.

Comment: @Tom This TImage control still has to re-draw itself, so the paint burden will be just the same. But now you'd need to make sure that the image was always painted first. Doing the whole paint in a paint box makes that very easy to achieve. Drawing a bitmap on a paintbox canvas is a one liner.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Actually, no. Image will stay intact - he will just change the Y coordinate of the once prepared TPaintBox.

Comment: @adlabac To the screen I mean. The image is drawn just as often to the screen.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What I meant is that it would be easier for Tom to program it this way, so he does not need to keep the image (or aprt of it) in the memory.

Comment: What is a TImage if it is not an in memory image. Drawing a bitmap to a paint box is a one liner. It could not be easy. Perhaps you haven't realised that yet which is why you think that drawing on a paint box is so hard.

Comment: Yes, it is one-liner, but it requires two times more memory, and it's much slower. It IS corect what you said, I just proposed the alternative.